# Is it a good way to access instance variable with self? If I use a lot

Tags: swift

```
class Persion: NSObject {
     var name = "John"

     func greeting() {
          let message = "Hello \(self.name)"
          print(message)
     }
}
```

take a look In greeting method of Persion class.
I'm using self.name that let me get clear "Im using instance variable now not local variable"
Is it a good way to access instance variable with self? If I use a lot.

Comment: no need to use self there let message = "Hello \\(name)"

Answer (score 5):

The question of whether to use `self` always, or only when necessary, is a matter of opinion. There has been a lot of debate on [the swift-evolution mailing list](https://lists.swift.org/mailman/listinfo/swift-evolution) about whether Swift should *require* the use of `self` to access instance variables, and [a formal proposal that it should](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0009-require-self-for-accessing-instance-members.md). The proposal (which was not made by a Swift core team member) has not yet been decided on as of this writing, but will probably be decided on soon (after Apple staffers return from vacation).

https://www.google.com/search?q=swift-evolution+mandatory+self+site:lists.swift.org

https://www.google.com/search?q=swift-evolution+require+self+instance+site%3Alists.swift.org

#### UPDATE

The proposal was rejected. Swift will not require you to use `self` to access instance variables. You can still choose to use it everywhere as part of your standard coding style, and maybe someone will write a “linter” that verifies that its input files use it everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Methods.html):

> In practice, you don’t need to write self in your code very often. If
>   you don’t explicitly write self, Swift assumes that you are referring
>   to a property or method of the current instance whenever you use a
>   known property or method name within a method.

So in my opinion only use `self`when needed to differentiate between a local and instance variable like `self.property = property` on a constructor.

Answer (score 0):

No, use self only when you really have to.

- Inside a closure - the compiler warns you anyway about it. This is to remind you that you could create a reference cycle between the closure and self.
- If a passed parameter in a func has the same name as a property variable or constant on self then you also must apply self to resolve the ambiguity.

Another argument against using "self":
If you use self all the time (without obvious reason) then you are going to forget the hidden danger of passing self and creating a reference cycle. It get's also way easier to do a text search in a class for "self" to find the possibillity of a reference cycle.

Apart from all the good reasons it is just reduntant - there is anyway color highlighting for properties in Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

It is preferred to use the self keyword which is more suited as in OOPS.