# self.property or property in Swift

Tags: swift, coding-style, self

In a Swift method you can access a property using `self.property` or simply `property`.

Is there any difference? Is one of these preferred? Is there any style guide published by Apple which requires one or the other?

Comment: Compare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34477188/is-it-a-good-way-to-access-instance-variable-with-self-if-i-use-a-lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In practice, you don’t need to write self in your code very often. If
>   you don’t explicitly write self, Swift assumes that you are referring
>   to a property or method of the current instance whenever you use a
>   known property or method name within a method.
>
> The main exception to this rule occurs when a parameter name for an
>   instance method has the same name as a property of that instance. In
>   this situation, the parameter name takes precedence, and it becomes
>   necessary to refer to the property in a more qualified way. You use
>   the self property to distinguish between the parameter name and the
>   property name.

Reference: [The Swift Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Methods.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH15-ID234) from Apple.